# Skips entry from pandas dataframe in url

Tags: python, pandas

Here is some code that works fine but I have no idea why it gets record503 but doesn't add it to the dataframe.  When trying to debug there was no "after df" for record503 >> see below for output.  Does anyone know why this would happen?

```
for i in range(500,505):
with urllib.request.urlopen("WEBSITE" + str(i)) as url:
    print('record'+str(i))#debug
    s = url.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser", from_encoding="utf-8")    
#DF1
try:    
    print('2') #debug
    Own_hist = []        
    print(Own_hist)#debug
    for ownvar in soup.find_all("table",{"id":"MainContent_grdSales"}):
        for ownvar2 in ownvar.find_all("td"):
            Own_hist.append(ownvar2.text)
    Own_hist_use = Own_hist[0:6]
    print(Own_hist_use)#debug
    #Own_hist_other = Own_hist[6:]
    print('before DF') #debug    
    print(i)#debug
    df_own_hist.loc[i] = Own_hist_use #DF5
    print('after df')#debug
except:
    pass
```

Here is the output hen I run the file

record500

2

[]

['CUCCARO KEVIN M &', '$443,000', '\xa0', '  4122/  73', '00', '04/01/2008']

before DF

500

after df

record501

2

[]

['MOY STEPHEN C & HELEN F C', '$399,000', '\xa0', '  4249/ 202', '00', '03/13/2009']

before DF

501

after df

record502

2

[]

['MILLER DANIEL', '$220,000', '\xa0', '  4429/ 219', '25', '04/01/2010']

before DF

502

after df

record503

2

[]

['HALL JAMES J & IRENE L', '$0', '\xa0', '   380/  61', '\xa0']

before DF

503

**?????? QUESTION WHY DOES THIS NOT PRINT TO DF???**

record504

2

[]

['MATTOON VIRGINIA G', '$0', '\xa0', '  1407/ 154', '07/20/1994', 'MATTOON CHARLES L & VIRGINIA G']

before DF

504

after df

Comment: Don't use full uppercase in the title.

Comment: ok - got it. Apologize for that